# jQuery scrollTop - animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

Using the example found [here](http://speckyboy.com/2012/03/07/scroll-to-internal-link-with-jquery/), I'm trying the implement the same. When I click on a navigation link, it jumps to the selected div instead of sliding/scrolling.

**HTML:**

Navigation

```
<div class="span3">
        <a href="#about-me"><img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/200x200/e36b23/fff/&text=About+Me+"></a>
</div>
```

DIV

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="about-me"> ... </div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
        var el = $(this).attr('href');
        var elWrapped = $(el);

        scrollToDiv(elWrapped,40);

        return false;
    });

    function scrollToDiv(element, navheight){
        var offset = element.offset();
        var offsetTop = offset.top;
        var totalScroll = offsetTop - navheight;

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: totalScroll
        }, 1000);
    }
});
</script>
```

So it's getting to the 'clicked' div but not with the slide animation - which is what I want. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Since your link is a valid anchor, I'd say you could well be seeing default behaviour because the jQuery isn't being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your jQuery selector to match your html classes - you aren't using the same `ul` / `li` that your cited example uses, e.g.

```
$('.span3 a').click(function(){
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhjyv/13/) for a fiddle:

Answer (score 1):

You do not prevent default behavior, which is to navigate ("jump") directly to the anchor point. So here it goes:

```
$('nav ul li a').click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```